# How to pass SVG content as a NSString to an UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, svg

I'm new to iOS and work on displaying mathematical terms in an appropriate notation on the iPad. I've learned that MathML is recently not supported by WebKit, so I'm trying to use SVG.

What I need is a simple example (or tutorial) of how to display a SVG-Element in an UIWebView by **passing the complete content (created dynamically) as a NSString to the UIWebView** - I don't want to make any use of files etc. and the App has to **work completely offline**.

P.S. Links to tutorials I've found, but they cover always loading e.g. pictures from a file etc.?

I appreciate any help (examples, links, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

maybe something like this

get NSData from NSString

```
NSData *svgData = [svgStr dataUsingEncoding:...];

then 

NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:resourcePath isDirectory:YES];

[self.webView   loadData:svgData 
    MIMEType:@"image/svg+xml"   
    textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" 
    baseURL:baseURL];   
[baseURL release];
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it worked! My fault was it, not to specify MIMEType etc. (Thomas Nitsche)

Comment: cool Thomas. it would be nice if you check this answer as an answer ^) peoples here very like this mark )))